# LP starts to flow when attached to grill with tank valve closed

Tags: propane

I have a new gas grill and when I attach the tank the gas starts to flow immediately without touching the valve on the tank, it is still closed. I have never owned a gas grill before so I'm in the dark on this.

Comment: What about the on/off valve for the grill?

Comment: Touch the tank valve. Turn it to close the valve and stop the flow.  Or turn the grill control knobs to the off position  then attach tank to grill

Comment: the gas starts flowing as soon as the grill is attached to tank with the valve on the tank turned off.

Answer (score 0):

It is a possibility it Is the regulator filling is that what you hear

Modern tanks with the over fill protection device usually have a shut off also that stops the gas flow (valve open) if the fitting is removed. When putting the fitting on you might hear a leak.

Turn the tank valve off connect the fitting and turn the valve on the tank on there may be a brief pressurization of the regulator and lines.

use soapy water solution to check for leaks.

The rubber seal at the back of the valve may be damaged I had one a while back that was damaged and I found a seal on line and was able to replace mine for under 2$ some say it can’t be done but mine worked.

The piece that you remove with a large screwdriver inside the valve is left hand threaded just like the gas fitting.

If it was the seal and you replaced it make sure to check with soapy water that there are no leaks, no bubbles no leaks

A friend said he just swapped them at blue rino but mine was a larger tank not the normal size.